# Xamarin Android: How to add android.support.v7.widget.SearchView in xaml

Tags: android, search, view, android-support-library

I am trying to use the SearchView in my application. I decided to use android.support.v7.widget.SearchView but the xamarin studio have an error when rendering the layout in the designer.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/lightGray">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/weatherLocation"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/material_grey_600"
    style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/abc_action_bar_subtitle_bottom_margin_material"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/abc_action_bar_subtitle_bottom_margin_material"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/abc_action_bar_subtitle_bottom_margin_material"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:text=""
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
    style="@style/SearchViewStyle"
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/weatherLocation"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/weatherLocation"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/weatherLocation"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

Message : Custom controls disabled. There was an internal issue with the rendering process.

Does that mean i have not installed the package? I can't see it on nuget in xamarin studio.

P.S. I can compile and run but will have inflating error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The packages you installed should be found in 'Installed' tab. If you can not find it, yes, it means you have not installed the package. You should install it on NuGet, search for 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.SearchView' and download it.

Comment: Now I have installed but still getting Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.SearchView

Comment: The error message now is changing, so the main issue is fixed. Could you try delete the obj/bin folder, then clean and rebuild your project? See if that could fix this issue.

Comment: Now it work if I change the activity to AppCompatActivity with @style/Theme.AppCompat.Light but I don't like the ActionBar on top. Before I called ActionBar.Hide but ActionBar is null after I put the theme on

Comment: If it still does not help, try checking your `Xamarin.Android.Support.v4` and `Xamarin.Android.Design` installed. Install them if you have not.

Comment: It works now once I placed the App.Compat.Light theme. Now I used App.Compat.NoActionBar to get rid of the bar  but it remove the search view though.

Comment: Is it compiled successfully though? The `SearchView` is gone but no error?

Comment: Yes it compiled but i think i leave the action bar there and place the search view on it. Thank for your help.